# Youtube video is encoded incorrectly and looks like its in 3d

Tags: youtube

I am not promoting this video, I really do need help. 
I was sent here for help from superuser. Please nicely let me know if this is also the wrong community.

My youtube video is uploaded several years ago. The video appears correctly When i view it in the editor. However when viewed from any web viewer like a computer or a phone it is all encoded incorrectly. It looks like the red and green color are encoded at different times. 
Please let me know who to ask or how to get the video re-encoded by youtube.
The video is

EDIT: output `ffmpeg -hide_banner -i /home/USER/Desktop/VID_20120415_132324.3gp'`

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp4
    minor_version   : 768
    compatible_brands: 3gp4mp413gp6
    creation_time   : 2012-04-15T18:23:35.000000Z
    copyright       : 
    copyright-eng   : 
    rating          : 0
    location-eng    : +00.0000+000.0000/��
    location        : +00.0000+000.0000/��
  Duration: 00:00:47.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1805 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1791 kb/s, 17.51 fps, 17.67 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-04-15T18:23:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: amr_nb (samr / 0x726D6173), 8000 Hz, mono, flt, 12 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-04-15T18:23:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: did you try to convert the 3gp to another format and use `H.264` codec or `VP-9`. Can you also post the output of `ffmpeg -hide_banner -i VID_20120415_132324.3gp` so that we can see the color space of the input file? If you happen to have `mediainfo`.

Comment: for some reason, Youtube seems to think that your video is 3D and if you change to 2d all the colors are OK. I guess you can change those settings at the time of upload, but again, I have never uploaded any videos on Youtube.

Comment: No, the video came off my iphone as a 3gp. See the output above.

Comment: Hmm, apart of the frame rate, which seems to be inconsistent, I don't see any other problem with this video. My guess is to just try to transcode it with ffmpeg before uploading it to youtube. The easiest will be just to use: `ffmpeg -i /home/USER/Desktop/VID_20120415_132324.3gp -c:v libx264 -b:v 1800k -c:a copy output.mp4` and then you can upload `output.mp4` to Youtube. If you want you can also upload your original file somewhere on the web and I can take a look at it.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, you can also transcode the audio to some other format and perhaps change it from mono to stereo. If you need help with the command, let me know.